# How to replace a data in arff file?

Tags: java, arff

I have an arff file that needs to be modified while keeping the same structure of the file each time I run the code.

For example I have the following arff file

```
@relation australian

@attribute A1 numeric
@attribute A2 numeric
@attribute A3 numeric
@attribute A4 numeric
@attribute A5 numeric
@attribute A6 numeric
@attribute A7 {0,1}

@data
1,3,5,2,4,3,1
3,5,1,2,5,6,0
6,1,4,2,3,4,1
```

I need to replace the three lines of data with another three lines each time I run the code

I use the following code but it appends the new data to the old data not replacing it.

```
 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("aa.txt"));
String toWrite = "";
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    toWrite += line;
   // System.out.println(toWrite);
}
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("colon.arff",true);
fw.write(toWrite);
fw.close();
```

Comment: thanks @Mad I do not have another code just I  used the above code and I found that it appends the data to the file while my request is to replace the old data with a new data

Answer (score 0):

To clear up a couple things:

---

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("colon.arff", true);
```

In your **FileWriter** declaration you utilize the boolean append flag as true which enables appending to the file supplied. I'm not sure this is really what you want considering the fact that you want the data being written to the file to be the very same format as the file being read. You wouldn't want the chance of anything to be appended to that file therefore distorting the original content format.

---

```
toWrite += line;
```

Doing concatenations like this within a loop is never really a good idea (yes, I still do it from time to time for simple things and demo purposes). Simple concatenations outside of a loop is fine since the compiler utilizes **StringBuilder** anyways if it thinks it will be more beneficial. It's just better to use the **StringBuilder** class for the following reason:

In Java, string objects are immutable, which means once it is created, you cannot change it. So when we concatenate one string with another, a new string is created, and the older one is marked for the garbage collector. Let's say we need to concatenate a million strings. Then, we are creating 1 million extra strings which will eventually be garbage collected.

To solve this problem, the **StringBuilder** class is used. It works like a mutable String object. The **StringBuilder#append()** method helps to avoid all the copying required in string concatenation. To utilize **StringBuilder** in your case you would declare the builder above the **while** loop:

```
StringBuilder toWrite = new StringBuilder();
```

and then within the loop:

```
toWrite.append(line).append(System.lineSeparator());
```

Notice the additional **append(System.lineSeparator())**? When you want to write a finished line to a file with **FileWriter** you need to add a Line Break ("\n" or "\r\n" depending on the OS) so that the next line that will need to be written will be on a new line within the file. In this case you are actually building the String that will be written to the file on a single write so if an appended string needs to be on a new line within the file then a line break needs to also be appended. The **System.lineSeparator()** method returns the Operating System dependent Line Break character(s).

---

The code below will do what you're asking:

```
// Demo data to replace in file...
String[] newData = {"4,2,13,1,4,2,0",
                    "1,3,3,5,2,4,1",
                    "7,7,2,1,5,8,1"};

// 'Try With Resourses' is used here to auto-close the reader and writer.
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("aa.txt")); 
                             FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("colon.arff")) {
    String ls = System.lineSeparator();  // The Line Break use by OS.
    StringBuilder toWrite = new StringBuilder(); // A String builder object
    int skip = 0; // Used for skipping old file data for placement of the new data
    String line = null; // Use to hold file lines read (one at a time)

    // Start reading file...
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        /* If skip is greater than 0 then read in next line and 
           decrement skip by 1. This is used in case the data 
           in file contains more rows of data than what you are 
           replacing.              */
        if (skip > 0) {
            skip--;
            continue;
        }

        // Append the file line read into the StringBuilder object
        toWrite.append(line).append(ls);

        // If the file line read equals "@data"
        if (line.trim().equals("@data")) {
            /* Append the new data to the toWrite variable here, 
               for example: if the new data was in a string array 
               named newData (see above declaration)...        */
            for (int i = 0; i < newData.length; i++) {
                /* Perform new data Validation...
                   Make sure all values are string representations
                   of numerical data and that the 7th column of data
                   is no less than 0 and no more than 1.          */
                String[] ndParts = newData[i].split("\\s{0,},\\s{0,}"); // Split the current data row
                boolean isValid = true;  // flag
                for (int v = 0; v < ndParts.length; v++) {
                    if (!ndParts[v].matches("\\d+") || 
                            (v == 6 && (!ndParts[v].equals("0") && 
                            !ndParts[v].equals("1")))) {
                        isValid = false;
                        System.err.println("Invalid numerical value supplied on Row " + 
                                (i+1) + " in Column " + (v+1) + ". (Data: " + newData[i] + ")" + 
                                ls + "Not writing data line to file!");
                        break;
                    }
                }
                /* If the current new data row is valid then append
                   it to the build and increment skip by 1.      */
                if (isValid) {
                    toWrite.append(newData[i]).append(ls);
                    skip++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // Write the entire built string to file.
    fw.write(toWrite.toString());
}
catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
}
catch (IOException ex) {
    System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```